# Wondering about a way to conserve memory in C# using List<> with structs

Tags: c#, list, reference, struct

I'm not even sure how I should phrase this question. I'm passing some CustomStruct objects as parameters to a class method, and storing them in a List.  What I'm wondering is if it's possible and more efficient to add multiple references to a particular instance of a CustomStruct if a equivalent instance it found.

This is a dummy/example struct:

```
public struct CustomStruct
{
    readonly int _x;
    readonly int _y;
    readonly int _w;
    readonly int _h;
    readonly Enum _e;
}
```

Using the below method, you can pass one, two, or three CustomStruct objects as parameters. In the final method (that takes three parameters), it may be the case that the 3rd and possibly the 2nd will have the same value as the first.

```
List<CustomStruct> _list;

public void AddBackground(CustomStruct normal)
{
    AddBackground(normal, normal, normal);
}

public void AddBackground(CustomStruct normal, CustomStruct hover)
{
    AddBackground(normal, hover, hover);
}

public void AddBackground(CustomStruct normal, CustomStruct hover, CustomStruct active)
{
    _list = new List<CustomStruct>(3);
    _list.Add(normal);
    _list.Add(hover);
    _list.Add(active);
}
```

As the method stands now, I believe it will create new instances of CustomStruct objects, and then adds a reference of each to the List.

It is my understanding that if I instead check for equality between **normal** and **hover** and (if equal) insert **normal** again in place of **hover**, when the method completes, **hover** will lose all references and eventually be garbage collected, whereas **normal** will have two references in the List.  The same could be done for **active**.

That would be better, right?  The CustomStruct is a ValueType, and therefore one instance would remain on the Stack, and the three List references would just point to it.  The overall List size is determined not by the object Type is contains, but by its Capacity.  By eliminating the "duplicate" CustomStuct objects, you allow them to be cleaned up.

When the CustomStruct objects are passed to these methods, new instances are created each time. When the structs are added to the List, is another copy made?  For example, if i pass just one CustomStruct, AddBackground(normal) creates a copy of the original variable, and then passes it three times to Addbackground(normal, hover, active). In this method, three copies are made of the original copy.  When the three local variables are added to the List using Add(), are additional copies created inside Add(), and does that defeat the purpose of any equality checks as previously mentioned?

Is there a better way to handle this?  Should the structs be passed as references to the methods to get around this?

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: By definition, value types don't have references -- only reference types have references. The storage for the value types end up in the array itself. Value types are only on the stack when they're not embedded in something else.

Comment: So with List<CustomStruct> I'd always end up with three CustomStruct objects in memory?  If I Add() the same ValueType object to the List multiple times, is a new object created in memory for each addition?

Comment: Is there evidence that this is actually eating up a lot of memory?  How big is this list, anyway?

Comment: Not large, really.  I was just trying to keep things efficient.  Still learning the language.  I appreciate the responses!

Comment: The list takes up memory proportional to its capacity, not its current length. When you have three CustomStructs in the list, you may actually have enough space for several more than that, depending on the algorithm the list uses for growth. But yes, when you add the "same" ValueType object to the List three times, you will be using at least as much memory as three times the size of that struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about garbage collection and structs in the same line, which doesn't make sense. Ultimately, every time you *look* at a struct it is likely to copy itself. If you want to re-use the same reference, then you either need a class, or you need to wrap the struct *in* a class (boxing; either inbuilt or manual).

What actually happens in your code is:

```
_list.Add(normal); // a **copy** of normal is set into the list
_list.Add(hover); // a **copy** of hover is set into the list
_list.Add(active); // a **copy** of active is set into the list
```

Which when you think about it is (space-wise) identical to:

```
_list.Add(normal); // a **copy** of normal is set into the list
_list.Add(normal); // a **copy** of normal is set into the list
_list.Add(normal); // a **copy** of normal is set into the list
```

Note that the copy *doesn't* go onto the stack (the struct=stack is a common myth). The data goes into the array (inside the `List<>`) which is on the heap. Passing the structs arount by reference would make no difference *whatsoever* to the behaviour of `Add` (it simply avoids copying the struct when passing it into *this* method, but memory-copy is fast).

Answer (score 1):

Note that everytime you pass a struct to a function as a parameter, or assign one variable to another, or in your case, add it to a list, a copy of the entire struct is created (in your case, 20 bytes will be copied).

Also note that there are no GC references to structs expect (I think) in some circumstances.

---

You will only get memory savings if you use a class instead of a struct - that way you can test for equality like you suggest.

Comment: re "I think": even if the struct is indirectly on the heap, the GC reference is to the containing class, not directly to the struct

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're mixing up the definition for value types and reference types a bit. Struct are value types, so variables store the actual values. An instance of a struct is not an object, and it will not be collected by the GC. A reference type variable stores a reference to an instance. Instances are stored on the heap and will eventually be collected by the GC.

Your list of structs is a reference type itself, so it will be stored on the heap along with its values. Each time you add an entry to the list the data is copied from the local representation in your method to one of the slots in the list. If you store the same value multiple times, it will be copied multiple times. It is just list a list of ints. If you have the value 42 ten times, you will find ten copies of the value 42 in memory for the list.